# How to remove/add class when another class is click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Below when class 'plus' is click all the hidden rows display.

By default they are hidden.

How can I get it to when the specific year is clicked, the months for that year will be shown.

With the below code they are shown all after click.

```
<cfoutput query="getdates" group="year">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> <span class="plus">+</span> #year#</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <cfif dtToday gte combineDates>
    <tbody class="closeAction">
      <cfoutput>
        <tr>
          <td><a href=""> #month#  </a></td>
        </tr>
      </cfoutput>
    </tbody>
  </cfif>
</cfoutput>

<style>
  .closeAction {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<script>
  $(".plus").click(function() {
    //$('.plus',this).html('-');
    $(".closeAction").removeClass("closeAction");
  })
</script>
```

This is how it looks before click:

[image]

Comment: If you could share some more of the final HTML showing multiple dates I could clean up my answer to be better than I have provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `closest()` and after `next()` (go to parent then search next element with provided classname) .

Also why note adding `close` class in adition to `closeAction` then use `toggleClass` to open/close date :

here is a working **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5yowntua/)**

And **Snippet**

```js
$(".plus").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('thead').next('.closeAction').toggleClass('closed');
})
```

```css
.closed {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr >
      <th> <span class="plus">+</span> 2015</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody  class="closeAction closed">
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#"> Jan </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#"> Feb  </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#"> Mar  </a></td>
    </tr>
  <thead>
    <tr >
      <th> <span class="plus">+</span> 2016</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody  class="closeAction closed">
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#"> #month#  </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#"> Jan </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#"> Feb  </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#"> Mar  </a></td>
    </tr>
  <thead>
    <tr >
      <th> <span class="plus">+</span> 2017</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody  class="closeAction closed">
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#"> Jan </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#"> Feb  </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#"> Mar  </a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, this work now i gotta figure it out adding the minus sign :)

Comment: Great :) I'm glad .

Comment: @anatp_123 for the minus sign
`$(".plus").click(function () {
  var text = '+';
    if ($(this).text() == '+') {
       text = '-';
    }
    $(this).text(text).closest('thead').next('.closeAction').toggleClass('closed');
})` Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5yowntua/1/

Answer (score 1):

`$(".closeAction")` is finding every element with this class in the DOM which is why they all open. You want to find the element with this class that is associated with that plus. Using `this` you can move up the DOM and find the element with that class starting from the context of the event. `this` is the context of the click event, the element the event was attached to which is the plus.

```
$(this).closest('thead').next().find('.closeAction').removeClass("closeAction");
```

This moves up to the closest `thead` element, gets the next element and finds all the elements with `closeAction` class inside that.

If you could show an example with more of the HTML this code could most likely be improved but since we are only working with a single example of a plus and closeAction its hard to know what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing considers all elements with class `closeAction`. You need to trigger the very next one. So, you can use `next()`

```
<script>
$(".plus").click(function () {
//$('.plus',this).html('-');
    $(this).next(".closeAction").removeClass("closeAction");
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.plus` and `.closeAction` elements seem to share the same `cfoutput` element, so you can traverse up to the closest `cfoutput` element and then from there, find the `.closeAction` element.

```
$(".plus").click(function () {
  $(this).closest("cfoutput").find('.closeAction').removeClass("closeAction");
})
```

Comment: Thats what I wanted to do too but those attributes `query="getdates" group="year"` seem to suggest all the years are grouped under the `cfoutput`. Just sharing some thoughts I had since my initial feeling was to find highest element and just do a find. But if all years are grouped under `cfoutput` then you will still find all `closeAction`s

Comment: True. I think the OP needs to provide more code in his example to get the right solution.

Comment: Absolutely agree! I have asked them to.